# In this pulley-block system, acceleration of blocks-A and B is same then how is their displacement different?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

[image: Question 130]

> In the given arrangement, Block C begins to move down at a constant speed of $7\  \rm{cm/s} $ at time $t=0$. At the same instant, Block A is made to start moving down at constant acceleration. When it covers $20\ \rm{cm}$, it’s speed is $30\  \rm{cm/s}$. Assuming that B started from rest, find its displacement, velocity and acceleration by the time A covers that $20\ \rm{cm}$

In question 130, let acceleration of:-

- Block A=$a$
- Block B=$b$
- Block C=$c$

Since the total length of the rope is constant, we have

$$x_A+2x_C+x_B=0\tag1$$
where $x_i$ is displacement of block $i$ in time $t$.
Differentiating equation (1) twice with respect to time, we have

$$a+2c+b=0$$

Since block C is not accelerating we have
$$c=0$$

Therefore,
$$a=-b$$

The value of $a$ is $-45/2\ \rm{cm/s^2}$ as obtained from equations of 1D motion with constant acceleration. Therefore value of $b=45/2\ \rm{cm/s^2}$. This means the displacement of Block B should be equal to the displacement of Block A since they both started at rest. But $20\ \rm{cm}$ length of the string is added by a motion of C. So that gives $x_B=40\ \rm{cm}\neq-x_A$, which contradicts what was derived earlier. How can I resolve this discrepancy?

Comment: Please write out the question instead of posting a picture of it. The picture won't show up in searches and is not accessible to everyone.

Comment: Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations.

Comment: But if I write out the question there will still be a diagram to portray...

Comment: I don’t know anything about MathJax... but I tried to make my reasoning clear

Comment: You can still put the diagram up. And I didn't say anything about your reasoning.

Comment: I’ve added the American dollars now<3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97277/discussion-between-ashish-raj-shukla-and-aaron-stevens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't your fault. The question is flawed. Differentiate the eq you got, $$x_A +x_B + 2x_C =0$$ to get $$v_A +v_B + 2v_C =0$$ At $t=0$ ,$v_A =0 , v_C = 7$ then $v_B$ can not be zero. Thus Block B can not start from rest.

Comment: That tells me,what if B acquired a velocity equal to twice of Block C,in dt time...

Comment: B did start from rest,but just like C,it acquired a velocity asap

Comment: @AshishRajShukla Right. If $A$ starts from rest and $C$ starts moving down at $7\ \rm{cm/s}$, then by the relations it must be that $B$ initially moves up with velocity $14\ \rm{cm/s}$